# ECLIPSE Subclipse: Occasional error with file selection in synchronize view

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am using Eclipse JUNO with the subclipse plugin.

Generally it works quite well. To commit files to the SVN repository you synchronize to check the changes you have made. Select the files you want to commit, add a comment and simply commit it.

Usually the selected files are then properly committed.

However, sometimes the selected files view in the commit window do not correspond to the actually selected files in the synchronize view. Instead it simply indicates all files in the project's file directory.

If you don't notice and commit you end up committing dozens of files/directories you do not want or need to commit.

I have tried all sorts of things to try and make it do that so that I know which chain of actions triggers it so I can avoid it but of course it never does it when you try.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing it or experienced the same? It is definitely not that the selected files are no longer selected. I could clearly see that selection still being active on the left hand side synchronization view but still the commit window was showing a full file selection.

Any help/suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Whatever file selection you do is overridden by a folder selection at a higher level => if you accidentally mark the project's main folder all files are transferred.

In the end it is Very simple and logical. The only nuisance is that the specific files you selected at a lower level are highlighted in the commit window's file selection view as well so if you look at the view superficially you get the impression only your selected files will be committed.